# Why is it that independent variable are plotted perpendicular to each other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-geometry

When we plot variable in Euclidean Space, why is it that the variable that are independent of each other, like x-coordinate, y-coordinate, lie on axes perpendicular to the other?

***  Edit: How do we know that projection of a quantity is equal to cos $\theta and nothing else?

Is it an axiom or something like that?

Thirdly, does that work even in other geometries?

Comment: Not to discredit you but, how can one conclude that to be true? I mean the reasoning and all that:)

Comment: $cos(\theta)=0$ if and only if the adjacent is zero (from the definition of cos), and this is the case only for a right triangle, i.e. perpendicular axes

Comment: Actually $x,y$ are still independent of each other in oblique coordinates...

Comment: "why is it that the variable that are independent of each other, like x-coordinate, y-coordinate, lie on axes perpendicular to the other?" We can draw whatever picture we want, the only question is whether or not the picture we draw turns out to be interesting.

Comment: I think the answer has to do with the fact that using the basis $(1,0), (0,1)$ is very convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motive for orthogonal axes is to construct a basis. If $\vec{X}=\sum_j X_j \vec{e}_j$ with $\vec{e}_j\cdot\vec{e}_k=\delta_{jk}$ (i.e. $1$ if $j=k$ or $0$ otherwise), $X_k=\vec{e}_k\cdot\vec{X}$ is unique. And since dot products scale as $\cos\theta=0$, our requirement is that the $\vec{e}_j$ are orthogonal.

But where, you asked, does the cosine come from? You can interpret vectors as matrices. The dot product of two vectors is the entry of a $1\times 1$ matrix $X^T Y$. If I multiply each vector on the left by a square matrix $R$, this result becomes $X^T R^T RY$. Rotations satisfy $R^T R=I$, leaving the dot product unchanged. Therefore we may as well assume one vector runs along the positive $x$-axis and other within the $xy$-plane, and then the dot product is just $XY\cos\theta$ by trigonometry.